# Xcode App Store Connect Operation Error: Could not find or load main class 12

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to upload my build to the App Store using Xcode 12 and I receive the error message:

> App Store Connect Operation Error
>
> Could not find or load main class 12

The app is built with SwiftUI. Has anyone faced a similar issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Any chance you had renamed the Xcode executable?

I originally experienced the same behavior (I had renamed Xcode.app to XcodeGM.app).
The issue went away after I closed Xcode & renamed the executable back to Xcode.app.

Note that my app is swift + some objc so I don't think that the language is a factor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes, the case was I've installed two versions of Xcode on my Mac. Thanks for the answer. I was surprised that there is no a similar question in stack overflow )))

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. I've changed the filename to "Xcode," but am still getting the same error message. Is it possible that there are vestiges of the old file name buried somewhere that need to be changed as well?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem... It was because I had several versions of Xcode on my computer.

Make sure the current version of Xcode you are using is titled `Xcode` and not `Xcode-beta`, `Xcode-2`, `Xcode 2` or anything other than just `Xcode`.

You can change the application's title in the Finder (you may need to rename the old version to something else first).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was because I download Xcode from browser and did not add Xcode to the applications. I add it and then run xcode from applications, app successfully uploaded.

edited:

I just simply drag Xcode(that I downloaded from browser) to the applications folder
[image]

Comment: For those who are not familiar with Xcode, you should provide a more detailed procedure of what you did to solve the problem.

Comment: I just simply drag Xcode(that I download)